# How check first 5 characters of auth.uid in Firebase Realtime Database rules?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I check for the authenticated user like this:

```
".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
```

Is it possible to check for the first 5 characters of the uid instead?

```
".write": "$uid === auth.uid.first5Characters"
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible based on two full UID values, but it also sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the use-case for comparing only the first 5 characters of both strings?

Comment: Hi Frank. To shorten the usernames in my JavaScript I would like to write only the 5 first characters of the uid into users of the database with `user.uid.substring(0, 5)` after anonymous authentication. But than I still want to make sure the user can only read/write in his own user entry in the database.

Comment: But if its not possible I have to find another way on the JavaScript side to display a shorter version of the uid.

Comment: Taking a substring like that will lead to many users have the same first 5 characters and won't be secure, so I strongly recommend not using this approach.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will only shorten the displayed uid in the ui than.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible based on two full UID values. But even if it was, it would not be secure as there's a decent likeliness that two UIDs will start with the same 5 characters.

If you want to use a shorter unique code to identify users, consider assigning your own code - and using your own mechanism to ensure their uniqueness.